# How to deal with low amount of animation frames on a high FPS game

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, sprite-sheet

Simply put: I am working on a 2d Platformer which runs with 80+ fps. I used to use a sprite sheet witch character which has a running animation with 20 pictures (frames) in total. Now I found a collection of characters which looks great but their running animations are about 9 pictures/frames and the gameplay looks super sloppy because of this. I was wondering do you know a way in which I can fake this and make this low frames looks better?

Comment: One possible workaround would be to make the animation execute twice as fast (but that probably wouldn't look great).

Comment: You can't solve this programmatically.